# Proper way of injecting dependencies

Tags: c#, oop, architecture, dependencies

I have a class which uses an injected handler to do something

```
class MyClass
{
    private readonly _handler;

    //Injected here
    public MyClass(IHandler handler)
    {
       _handler=handler;
    }

    public MyMethod(Param p)
    {
        var request= Transform(p);
        _handler.DoSomething(Request1 request)
    }
}
```

Now depending upon the situation, I might have another implementation of `IHandler`, but which might take `Request2` to `DoSomething()`. I can make `Request1` and `Request2` derive from a base `RequestBase`, and can change the `IHandler` implementation of `DoSomething()` take `RequestBase`. But before calling the `DoSomething()` I still need to know which specific `Request` (`Request1` or `Request2`) to pass, which breaks the purpose of injecting the dependency at the first place.  Can someone suggest a better way to do this? Or this is a completely wrong way of looking at it?

Comment: `which breaks the purpose of injecting the dependency at the first place` dependency injection is not related to what you're trying to pass, so your problem is not related to DI at all

Comment: answer to your question: each instance of IHandler must work with Request1 - it is the contract you've created. it cannot `might take Request2`. Probably you need to adjust your IHandler to provide another method 'doSomethingWithRequest2`

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to implement `IHandler` with a generic that is the accepted parameter type of `DoSomething`.

```
interface IHandler<T> 
{
    void DoSomething(T p)
}
```

That will then remove the need for your `Transform` method.

If `request1` and `request2` inherit from a `BaseRequest` (for example) you could change it to the below.

```
interface IHandler<T> where T : BaseRequest 
{
    void DoSomething(T p)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code breaks encapsulation and introduces a strong coupling in these two lines:

```
    var request= Transform(p);
    _handler.DoSomething(Request1 request)
```

Subtle as it is, all implementations of `IHandler.DoSomething` are tightly coupled to `Transform`.

Instead of the above, I would make the operations inside `Transform` part of the implementation of `DoSomething`.

Elaborating on the strong coupling I mention in opening... Because your code is written in a procedural manner, the bevaiour of  `DoSomething` depends on what `Transform` returns, that is, all implementations of `DoSomething` will need to know what to expect from `Transform` in order to fulfill their requirements.

In addition to this, the method `MyMethod` has very intimate knowledge of the internals of `Transform` in order to orchestrate the sequence of calls in these two lines of code. This is where encapsulation is violated.